# reducebit image from 24 bit rgb to 8 bit rgb but result image not beautiful as same as from tinypng.com

Tags: php, image, image-processing, colors, quantization

i use imagetruecolortopallete to reducebit image from 24 bit rgb to 8 bit rgb but result image not beautiful as same as from tinypng.com how can i do ?

[original image 24 bit rgb](http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/if/151212024837.png)

[image 8 bit rgb convert by my code](http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/ir/151212024957.png)

[image: 24bit]

[image: 8bit bad]

[image 8 bit rgb convert by tinypng.com](http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/ig/151212025126.png)

[image: 8bit ok]

**[Spektre]: sorry for not whole image but I lost the patience the source link is too slow/unstable (this took ~20 min after 3th attempt to download it ...)**

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(1024, 768);
imagetruecolortopalette($im, true, 255);
imagepng($im, 'cat.png');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: see [Effective gif/image color quantization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214) If you got too high colors dynamic range then the only option is dithering... WoW those links of yours are SLOOOW