# Is there a better than O(N^2) Algorithm to take a set of colors and return colors that contrast or are dissimilar?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, colors, color-theory

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that can take a set of colors X and return a new set of colors X' that consists of only contrasting colors from the original set X. In other words I want to filter out similar colors from the passed in color set. If you would like to think in terms of color differencing, the problem can be thought of filtering out all colors that are <= some distance k from any color in the set.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in linear time or O(N). I am ok with other time complexities as well as long as it is not O(N^2), every solution I come up with takes polynomial time. I tried reducing the problem to the famous "find all pairs of integers in an array that sum to K" but that reduction did not work. I am using the deltaE metric to determine how far apart or dissimilar/contrasting two colors are.

Comment: not sure what you are doing this for (not clear from your other question too) but I think you are looking for **Color Quantization** methods which are for reducing the number of used colors in an image with as small impact on quality as possible ... usually clustering methods are used for this see [Effective gif/image color quantization?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214) to speed up you can use search LUT tables so `O(N^2)`  became `O(N.log(N))` or even less

Comment: If you want to generate new colors  then you should use geometry approach which is `O(N^2)` like you did but you have to take into account that `N^2` is number of returned colors .... so you can not get lower then that

Answer (score 0):

Use a [cover tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree) to store colors under the ∆E metric. For each color, do an O(log n)-time proximity search in the cover tree and reject it if the nearest color is too close.

Comment: what do you mean by O(logN) time proximity search? By that I assume you mean find all nearest neighbors for a given point (color), basically all colors/points within a ball radius. It says that operation is O(N). That should give me a worst case time complexity of N^2 again. Its even worse because this N is not my passed in color set I am filtering but the space of all RGB colors which is (256)^3 points.
I am getting the time complexity from here:
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos598E/bib/covertree.pdf
Look at Theorom 3.7 on page 10.
Thanks for the response :)

Comment: @AyBayBay FindAllNearest finds, *for each point*, its closest neighbor. You want plain FindNearest, which has running time O(c^12 log n), and c is constant for you (not to mention that c^12 is probably a significant overestimate in practice).

Comment: so running the query find all nearest for a point p within a radius R is logN complexity? That is awesome!

Comment: It has just occured to me my deltaE metric (using the CIE94 algorithm). Does not satisfy the symmetry property of a distance metric: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)

Would this then be a problem to use deltaE as the distance metric for my cover tree? I read somewhere all the distance metric needs to satisfy is the triangle inequality to be used in metric tree structures.

Comment: @AyBayBay Yeah, that's a problem.

Comment: So in order for a distance metric to be used in a cover tree (or any metric tree structures), the distance metric must satisfy all three properties:
[1. d(x,y) = 0 if and only if x = y
2. d(x,y) = d(y,x) symmetry
3. Triangle inequality]...

Is my understanding correct? If this is the case, I found a new DeltaE metric that uses Euclidean Distance in the LAB color space. If I use this DeltaE metric, then I could probably just use a simpler KD-tree right? Once again thank you for the help :)

Comment: @AyBayBay Yes to that.

Comment: Why can't the distance metric be a quasi-metric? In real-life I feel like symmetry is harder to satisfy (think maps/navigation and routing).

Comment: nevermind if symmetry does not work fundamental comparison will just fail