# Change number of colors for each pixel in .gif image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

Is it possible to remape (for example) a 256-colors-gif image into a 128-colors or 64-colors gif image in Python?

I tried it using the imageio library

```
import imageio

def myfunction(inputgif, outputgif, duration):
  gifimage = imageio.mimread(inputgif)
  for i in range(len(gifimage)):
     gifimage[i] = gifimage[i]/4

  with imageio.get_writer(outputgif, mode='I', duration=duration) as writer:
      for x in range(len(gifimage)):
        writer.append_data(gifimage[x])
  writer.close()
```

It's working, but, the problem is that the image file still thinks that "his universe" is 256 possible values for the color (from 0 to 255), not from 0 to 64 (since I divided all the values by 4). Which makes the image goes only darker, instead of using a 64 (4 bits) possible colors.

My goal is to obtain a lossy data compression by decreasing number of colors.

Comment: You know, that a sane approach will use some kind of vector-quantization (to optimize the kept colors) and a custom-color palette (only using the previously calculated colors)? This is very different from your code! I don't know what you expect with your approach (it does a linear color-transform in some space; far away from lossy depending on your expectation). There are probably many libs doing exactly this, but implementing this all yourself with python might be some work.

Comment: @sascha thank you. Can you give me some examples on the libraries which I can use please?

Comment: Well, one of the most popular ones (in the open-source world): [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/).

Comment: Why do you want to compress ?

Comment: see [Effective gif/image color quantization?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

The GIF format only supports palette entries on 8 bits.

Even if it supported less, the savings would be marginal: 12.5% for 7 bits, 25% for 6 bits.

Comment: But I can generate a .gif image which is smaller than the original if I changed the color palette from 256 to 128 or 64, 32.. etc? That's my goal. I found a small option in the imageio library which is "palettesize=n" to set that setting.

Comment: You don't understand: GIF does not support that.

Comment: What I know is that is supports "maximum 8", but I can see the results in my eyes. I changed the palettesize for a .gif image and I obtained a very smaller .gif image.