# Need a suggestion for a color palette data structure for iterative color quantization; in particular, any experiences with KD heaps?

Tags: data-structures, graphics, kdtree, quantization, color-palette

I am implementing color quantization that works in iterations. During each iteration, a new color palette is built up, and then that palette is searched through many times for the palette entry that best matches a given RGB triplet.

Also, I need to be able to access the palette in an array-like fashion so I can construct the final image later. My immediate thought was a KD tree that only contains references to array entries. But, rebuilding such a sparse data structure does not sound ideal, at least in the naive way, since it means (re)allocating space for KD nodes all the time.

I suppose a better approach would be to never actually free nodes, but instead just mark them as unused. This would allow for much faster rebuilding, since reallocations would only happen if more nodes are needed.

Still, something that intrinsically works within an array-like structure would be even better, since it would be more CPU cache friendly. So I stumbled upon KD heaps. [Here is a brief Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-D_heap), and [here is the paper about it](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-57155-8_257). The basic idea seems to be an extension of the heap property, and this would make it work within the array. So, this sounds ideal, since heaps typically are implemented with an array. But I have never used KD heaps, so I am not sure if there's a catch.

So, would you use KD heaps for being able to find the closest matching color in color palettes? If not, what other data structure would you recommend that can be constructed quickly and efficiently?

("Constructing" means here that the entire palette data structure is constructed at once with all color values; they do not get added one by one.)

Comment: what exactly you need this for? the incremental palette description sounds like XY problem. Take a look at this: [Effective gif/image color quantization?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214) its also iterative like but there is no need for weird structures storing previous palettes ...

Comment: If I had to do it the way you say it, I would use a K-D tree packed into an array so that I didn't have to store any pointers...  But are you sure there isn't a relationship between new and old versions of the palette that would let you repartition the colors more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was thinking too complicated. Also, there was a bug elsewhere that drastically impacted performance. A K-D tree packed in an array works fine, and with that other bug fixed, everything is OK.