# Question regarding color histogram based methods of generating color lookup-up tables

Tags: graphics, histogram, rgb, lookup, quantization

I have a piece of code that needs to conform to a research paper's implementation of a color quantization algorithm for a 256 entry LUT whose 24-bit color entries are derived from a "population count" color histogram algorithm. The problem is that I don't know how the authors originally implemented their histogram algorithm -- the paper is a little ambiguous. Currently, I index a 2^24 entry array of integers based on a pixel's raw RGB 24-bit color triple, and increment the particular indexed entry in the array. I then sort the histogram and then I organize it into an effective 15-bit color space by putting blocks of 512 color counts into bins and taking the arithmetic mean of all the colors in the bin. I then stuff 256 averaged color values, starting with the largest color count, in decreasing order of color count into a 256 entry 24-bit color LUT. The output is very disappointing though and low quality. I know that vector quantization or something like median-cut would be better, but I'm constrained to do it with a histogram. I've extensively searched, using google, for "population count" histogram algorithms, but none of the search results were very helpful.

For reference, I'll include the original 512x512 pixel 24-bit color image along with its histogram based color LUT counterpart :

[image: Original, uncompressed 24-bit color image]

[image: Image after color quantization based on 256 entry LUT]

If anyone could provide some ideas or suggestions of where to look for the right algorithm, I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks,

jdb2

Comment: FWIW, I would think that using histograms would be a relatively poor way of producing a palette (i.e. a type of Vector Quantised) image.  Although old, IMHO, Paul Heckbert's [*"Color Image Quantization for Frame Buffer Display" *](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2310359_Color_Image_Quantization_for_Frame_Buffer_Display) would do a much better job and, IIRC, is easy to implement. You can do better using Principal Component Analysis (e.g, Xiaolin Wu's method) and also by applying K-Means etc.

Answer (score 2):

try this [Effective gif/image color quantization?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214) its also histogram color quantization based, very similar to your approach but it create the histogram from 15 bit colors directly to spare space and do not use bins instead it sort colors by occurrence and use min distance to already used colors in palette thresholding to avoid almost duplicate colors... I developed it for my GIF encoder lib some years back...

If I take this as input (converted to jpg):

[image: 24bpp]

And use mine algo on it without dithering I got this result:

[image: 8bpp no dither]

With dithering enabled I got this result:

[image: 8bpp with dithering]

as you can see on the cat ear the dithering is much better but even without dithering the result is way better than yours.

However over the years the palette computation code evolves a bit (from the one posted in linked answer) into this (**C++**):

```cpp
void gif::compute_palette0()
    {
    int x,y,r0,g0,b0,r,g,b,a,aa,c,e,hists;
    DWORD i,i0,cc;
    union { DWORD dd; BYTE db[4]; } c0,c1;
    DWORD his[32768];
    DWORD idx[32768];
    // 15bit histogram
    for (x=0;x<32768;x++) { his[x]=0; idx[x]=x; }
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++)
     for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
        {
        cc=pic.pyx[y][x];
        cc=((cc>>3)&0x1F)|((cc>>6)&0x3E0)|((cc>>9)&0x7C00);
        if (his[cc]<0xFFFFFFFF) his[cc]++;
        }
    // add RGB shades combinations for dithering
    if (_dither)
        {
        x=xs*ys;    // max possible count to make as start colors in palette
        for (r=0;r<32;r+=10)
         for (g=0;g<32;g+=10)
          for (b=0;b<32;b+=10,x++)
           his[(r<<10)|(g<<5)|( b)]=x;
        }
    // set recolor as unused
    for (r0=0;r0<32;r0++)
     for (g0=0;g0<32;g0++)
      for (b0=0;b0<32;b0++)
       recolor[r0][g0][b0]=255;
    // remove zeroes
    for (x=0,y=0;y<32768;y++)
        {
        his[x]=his[y];
        idx[x]=idx[y];
        if (his[x]) x++;
        } hists=x;
    // sort by hist
    for (i=1,e=hists;i;e--)
     for (i=0,x=0,y=1;y<e;x++,y++)
      if (his[x]<his[y])
        {
        i=his[x]; his[x]=his[y]; his[y]=i;
        i=idx[x]; idx[x]=idx[y]; idx[y]=i; i=1;
        }
    // set lcolor color palete
    for (i0=0,x=0;x<hists;x++) // main colors
        {
        cc=idx[x];
        b= cc     &31;
        g=(cc>> 5)&31;
        r=(cc>>10)&31;
        c0.db[0]=b;
        c0.db[1]=g;
        c0.db[2]=r;
        c0.dd=(c0.dd<<3)&0x00F8F8F8;
        // skip if similar color already in lcolor[]
        for (a=0,i=0;i<i0;i++)
            {
            c1.dd=lcolor[i];
            aa=int(BYTE(c1.db[0]))-int(BYTE(c0.db[0])); if (aa<=0) aa=-aa; a =aa;
            aa=int(BYTE(c1.db[1]))-int(BYTE(c0.db[1])); if (aa<=0) aa=-aa; a+=aa;
            aa=int(BYTE(c1.db[2]))-int(BYTE(c0.db[2])); if (aa<=0) aa=-aa; a+=aa;
            if (a<=16) { a=1; break; } a=0; // *** treshold ***
            }
        if (a) recolor[r][g][b]=i;
        else{
            recolor[r][g][b]=i0;
            lcolor[i0]=c0.dd; i0++;
            if (i0>=DWORD(lcolors)) { x++; break; }
            }
        }   // i0 = new color table size
    for (;x<hists;x++)  // minor colors
        {
        cc=idx[x];
        b= cc     &31;
        g=(cc>> 5)&31;
        r=(cc>>10)&31;
        c0.db[0]=b;
        c0.db[1]=g;
        c0.db[2]=r;
        c0.dd=(c0.dd<<3)&0x00F8F8F8;
        // find closest color
        int dc=-1; DWORD ii=0;
        for (a=0,i=0;i<i0;i++)
            {
            c1.dd=lcolor[i];
            aa=int(BYTE(c1.db[0]))-int(BYTE(c0.db[0])); if (aa<=0) aa=-aa; a =aa;
            aa=int(BYTE(c1.db[1]))-int(BYTE(c0.db[1])); if (aa<=0) aa=-aa; a+=aa;
            aa=int(BYTE(c1.db[2]))-int(BYTE(c0.db[2])); if (aa<=0) aa=-aa; a+=aa;
            if ((dc<0)||(dc>a)) { dc=a; ii=i; }
            }
        recolor[r][g][b]=ii;
        }
    encode_palette_compute(true);

    if ((frame)&&(hists<lcolors))
     for (lcolor_bits=1,lcolors=1<<lcolor_bits;lcolors<hists;lcolors<<=1,lcolor_bits++);
    // compute recolor for 16 base colors for all yet unused colors
    for (r0=0;r0<32;r0++)
     for (g0=0;g0<32;g0++)
      for (b0=0;b0<32;b0++)
       if (recolor[r0][g0][b0]==255)
        {
        // find closest color
        for (i=0,c=-1;i<16;i++)
            {
            c0.dd=lcolor[i];
            b=WORD(c0.db[0])>>3;
            g=WORD(c0.db[1])>>3;
            r=WORD(c0.db[2])>>3;
            a=(r-r0); aa =a*a;
            a=(g-g0); aa+=a*a;
            a=(b-b0); aa+=a*a;
            if ((c<0)||(e>aa)) { e=aa; c=i; }
            }
        recolor[r0][g0][b0]=c;
        }
    }
```

Where my `gif` class looks like this (so you can extract config and used variables...):

```cpp
class gif
    {
public:
    // IO interface
    file_cache<4<<20> fi,fo;        // file cache
    BYTE dat[256];                  // internal buffer 256 Bytes needed

    // Performance counter
    double Tms,tms,tdec,tenc;       // perioda citaca [ms], zmerany cas [ms],cas encodovania [ms]
    void tbeg();                    // zaciatok merania
    void tend();                    // koniec merania

    // image data
    gif_frame32 pic,pic0;           // actual and restore to 32bit frames
    gif_frame8  pic1;               // 8bit input conversion frame

    int xs,ys;                      // resolution
    int *py;                        // interlace table

    // colors (colors are computed from color_bits)
    DWORD gcolor[256];              //hdr
    DWORD lcolor[256];              //img
    BYTE  recolor[32][32][32];      //encode reduce color table
    int scolors,scolor_bits;        //hdr screen color depth
    int gcolors,gcolor_bits;        //hdr global pallete
    int lcolors,lcolor_bits;        //img/hdr local palette

    // info
    bool _89a;                      //hdr extensions present?
    bool _interlaced;               //img interlaced frame?
    bool _gcolor_table;             //hdr
    bool _gcolor_sorted;            //hdr
    bool _lcolor_table;             //img local palette present?
    bool _lcolor_sorted;            //img local palette colors sorted?
    int  cpf,cpf_error;             //clears per frame counter,clear_errors total
    // debug
    bool _draw_palette;             //draw pallete?

    // animation
    int frame,disposal;             // frame ix,disposal of frame
    double t,tn;                    // animation time,next frame time

    // encode config
    int _force_disposal;            // -1 or forced disposal
    bool _precomputed_palette;      // if true recolor and global palete is already set before encoding
    bool _dither;                   // dither colors?

    // inter thread comm
    volatile bool _image_copied;    // flag that source image is not needed anymore while encoding

    // temp dictionary for dec/enc
    gif_str dict[_gif_maxdecode];
    DWORD dicts,code_clr,code_end,code_min;
    // temp dictionary speed up tables (encoding)
    WORD dtab[256][_gif_maxencode],dnum[256],dmask[256];    // dtab[i][dnum[i]] all dictionary codes (sorted by code) starting with i for encode speed up, 1<<dmask[i]<=dnum[i]

    #pragma pack(1)
    struct __hdr
        {
        // Header
        BYTE Signature[3];      /* Header Signature (always "GIF") */
        BYTE Version[3];        /* GIF format version("87a" or "89a") */
        // Logical Screen Descriptor
        WORD xs;
        WORD ys;
        BYTE Packed;            /* Screen and Color Map Information */
        BYTE BackgroundColor;   /* Background Color Index */
        BYTE AspectRatio;       /* Pixel Aspect Ratio */
        __hdr(){}; __hdr(__hdr& a){ *this=a; }; ~__hdr(){}; __hdr* operator = (const __hdr *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*__hdr* operator = (const __hdr &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        };
    struct _hdr:__hdr
        {
        DWORD adr,siz;
        _hdr(){}; _hdr(_hdr& a){ *this=a; }; ~_hdr(){}; _hdr* operator = (const _hdr *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_hdr* operator = (const _hdr &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        } hdr;

    struct __img
        {
        // Logical Image Descriptor
        BYTE Separator;         /* Image Descriptor identifier 0x2C */
        WORD x0;                /* X position of image on the display */
        WORD y0;                /* Y position of image on the display */
        WORD xs;                /* Width of the image in pixels */
        WORD ys;                /* Height of the image in pixels */
        BYTE Packed;            /* Image and Color Table Data Information */
        __img(){}; __img(__img& a){ *this=a; }; ~__img(){}; __img* operator = (const __img *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*__img* operator = (const __img &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        };
    struct _img:__img
        {
        DWORD adr,siz;
        _img(){}; _img(_img& a){ *this=a; }; ~_img(){}; _img* operator = (const _img *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_img* operator = (const _img &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        } img;

    struct __gfxext
        {
        BYTE Introducer;        /* Extension Introducer (always 21h) */
        BYTE Label;             /* Graphic Control Label (always F9h) */
        BYTE BlockSize;         /* Size of remaining fields (always 04h) */
        BYTE Packed;            /* Method of graphics disposal to use */
        WORD DelayTime;         /* Hundredths of seconds to wait    */
        BYTE ColorIndex;        /* Transparent Color Index */
        BYTE Terminator;        /* Block Terminator (always 0) */
        __gfxext(){}; __gfxext(__gfxext& a){ *this=a; }; ~__gfxext(){}; __gfxext* operator = (const __gfxext *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*__gfxext* operator = (const __gfxext &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        };
    struct _gfxext:__gfxext
        {
        DWORD adr,siz;
        _gfxext(){}; _gfxext(_gfxext& a){ *this=a; }; ~_gfxext(){}; _gfxext* operator = (const _gfxext *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_gfxext* operator = (const _gfxext &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        } gfxext;

    struct __txtext
        {
        BYTE Introducer;        /* Extension Introducer (always 21h) */
        BYTE Label;             /* Extension Label (always 01h) */
        BYTE BlockSize;         /* Size of Extension Block (always 0Ch) */
        WORD TextGridLeft;      /* X position of text grid in pixels */
        WORD TextGridTop;       /* Y position of text grid in pixels */
        WORD TextGridWidth;     /* Width of the text grid in pixels */
        WORD TextGridHeight;    /* Height of the text grid in pixels */
        BYTE CellWidth;         /* Width of a grid cell in pixels */
        BYTE CellHeight;        /* Height of a grid cell in pixels */
        BYTE TextFgColorIndex;  /* Text foreground color index value */
        BYTE TextBgColorIndex;  /* Text background color index value */
//      BYTE *PlainTextData;    /* The Plain Text data */
//      BYTE Terminator;        /* Block Terminator (always 0) */
        __txtext(){}; __txtext(__txtext& a){ *this=a; }; ~__txtext(){}; __txtext* operator = (const __txtext *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*__txtext* operator = (const __txtext &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        };
    struct _txtext:__txtext
        {
        DWORD adr,siz;
        AnsiString dat;
        _txtext(){}; _txtext(_txtext& a){ *this=a; }; ~_txtext(){}; _txtext* operator = (const _txtext *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_txtext* operator = (const _txtext &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        };
    List<_txtext> txtext;

    struct __remext
        {
        BYTE Introducer;        /* Extension Introducer (always 21h) */
        BYTE Label;             /* Comment Label (always FEh) */
//      BYTE *CommentData;      /* Pointer to Comment Data sub-blocks */
//      BYTE Terminator;        /* Block Terminator (always 0) */
        __remext(){}; __remext(__remext& a){ *this=a; }; ~__remext(){}; __remext* operator = (const __remext *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*__remext* operator = (const __remext &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        };
    struct _remext:__remext
        {
        DWORD adr,siz;
        AnsiString dat;
        _remext(){}; _remext(_remext& a){ *this=a; }; ~_remext(){}; _remext* operator = (const _remext *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_remext* operator = (const _remext &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        };
    List<_remext> remext;

    struct __appext
        {
        BYTE Introducer;        /* Extension Introducer (always 21h) */
        BYTE Label;             /* Extension Label (always FFh) */
        BYTE BlockSize;         /* Size of Extension Block (always 0Bh) */
        CHAR Identifier[8];     /* Application Identifier */
        BYTE AuthentCode[3];    /* Application Authentication Code */
//      BYTE *ApplicationData;  /* Point to Application Data sub-blocks */
//      BYTE Terminator;        /* Block Terminator (always 0) */
        __appext(){}; __appext(__appext& a){ *this=a; }; ~__appext(){}; __appext* operator = (const __appext *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*__appext* operator = (const __appext &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        };
    struct _appext:__appext
        {
        DWORD adr,siz;
        AnsiString dat;
        _appext(){}; _appext(_appext& a){ *this=a; }; ~_appext(){}; _appext* operator = (const _appext *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*_appext* operator = (const _appext &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
        };
    List<_appext> appext;
    #pragma pack()

    gif();
    gif(gif& a);
    ~gif();
    gif* operator = (const gif *a);
    //gif* operator = (const gif &a);

    void _resize(int _xs,int _ys);                  // resize buffers
    void load_beg(AnsiString filename);             // open GIF file for decoding
    void decode(int _ignore_delay=0);               // decode frame from GIF, if _ignore_delay then ignore realtime
    void load_end();                                // close GIF file
    void save_beg(AnsiString filename);             // create new GIF file for encoding
    void compute_palette0();                        // compute palette from frame method 0
    void compute_palette1();                        // compute palette from frame method 1
    void encode_palette_RGB256();                   // set RGB combinations as 256 color palette as predefined global only palette
    void encode_palette_VGA256();                   // set default 256 color VGA palette as predefined global only palette
    void encode_palette_compute(bool _local);       // compute recolor[][][] from palette
    void encode(const gif_frame32 &src,int dt=0);   // encode frame to GIF , dt is delay in [ms] instead of realtime in range <10 .. 655350> [ms]
//  void encode(int dst_xs,int dst_ys,TCanvas *src,int src_x0,int src_y0,int src_x1,int src_y1,int dt=0);   // encode frame to GIF , dt is delay in [ms] instead of realtime in range <10 .. 655350> [ms]
    void save_end();                                // finalize and close GIF file
    void draw_info(int x,int y,TCanvas *can);
    void draw_info(int x,int y,Graphics::TBitmap *bmp);
    void configure(gif &src);                       // set all encoding variables from src (for multithreaded encoding)
    };
```

Comment: My question is too long to fit into the comment box so I'll have to break it up. Here's part 1 :

---

Well, I am using the FreeImage library in ANSI C, so I don't have to deal with the nitty-gritty details of loading and saving image files.

From your referenced post, I have a few questions :

"convert to 15-bit rgb"

I can already do this easily and, my code creates debug images using just 15-bits per pixel color quantization which look decent.

"do a histogram"

What type?
(Continued in part 2 of comment...)

Comment: (Comment part 2)
"15-bit rgb lead to 32768 entries so create 2 arrays
his[32768] is the pixel count (histogram)
idx[32768] is index = color value"

In my code,  have a structure which keeps the color counts associated with the color values. I'm not exactly sure why you're using two arrays.

"While counting colors ensure that counters do not overflow if using low bit count or high resolutions"

I count colors by indexing a 2^24 entry array and incrementing the indexed color's count. (Continued in part 3 of comment...)

Comment: (Comment part 3)
"reorder arrays so zeros in his[] are at the end of array"

I'm not quite sure I follow you here. Do you mean sort the array?

"also count the non zero entries in his[] and call it hists"

I already do this in my code by the nature of its design.

"(index) sort hist[],idx[] so hist[] is ordered descending;"

Not quite sure what you're saying here.

"create the N-color palette"

N would be 256 in my case, and, it's this stage at which the image quality is massively degraded. (Continued in comment part 4...)

Comment: (Comment part 4)
"Take color idx[i] (i={ 0,1,2,3,...,hists-1 }) and look if in your palette is no similar color. if is ignore this color (set it as the most close one found) otherwise add it to palette. if you reach the N colors stop"

I already do this using a squared Euclidean distance metric -- crude but functional.

"create color mapping"

Note quite sure what you mean here.

"So take each color and find the most close color in palette (this can be partially done in step 5) I call this table recolor[32][32][32]"

Again, not quite sure what you mean.

"recolor image"

? :/

Comment: @jdb2 when you do a 15 bit histogram then `his[32768]` is like bucket sort ... holding all possible colors count (even unused as 0 count) when I sort the `his[]` descending I need to know which entry is for which color as after sort the index in array is no longer the same as color that is what `idx[]` is for so whatever swaps/reordering you do on `his[]` you do also on `idx[]` the `his[],idx[]` is then used just as a list (no longer bucket sort) where color `idx[i]` has `his[i]` counts. If you doing histogram on used colors only instead then its much much slower....

Comment: @jdb2 similarly `recolor[r][g][b]` table is for speeding up the conversion and holds closest color for each possible 15 bit color (even unused in image) from the reduced palette. So instead of slow linear or binary search of palette for each pixel you just do `O(1)` LUT fetch ...