# Given a color, how can I organize a color palette to quickly find the most similar color inside of it?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, matrix, colors, algebra

Suppose I can define a color **c** as **c = (c<sub>r</sub> , c<sub>g</sub> , c<sub>b</sub>)**, where c<sub>r</sub> , c<sub>g</sub>  and c<sub>b</sub> are floats between 0 and 1 (inclusively).

Suppose I have an input color **c** and a matrix **M** of dimensions **m**×**n**, whose elements M[i][j] are colors.

How can I organize the elements of **M** so that I can develop an algorithm that finds the color inside **M** that is the most similar to **c**?

Similarity can be measured by euclidian distance or any other metrics.

Ideally, I would not use any data structures in the algorithm, because this is something that is going to run in the GPU and it doesn't use data structures.

Comment: Could you use a sampler with the colors arranged according to HSL? Two dimensions are not enough to describe a color.

Comment: How big is M likely to be, non-abstractly?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I havent defined it yet, but maybe somewhere around 30 to 50 colors

Comment: @aptriangle I guess, maybe... not very familiar with HSL but sounds like an idea

Comment: for 20-50 colors I would use naive linear search ... any advanced method either require "huge" [LUT of reindex values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214) or have bigger overhead which will gain speed only when number of colors is much bigger